# Is $\sum_{i =1}^\infty (i - 1)$ summable?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\sum_{i =1}^\infty (i - 1)$.

Does this series converge to infinity or $0$?

The problem for me is that you can group the terms either way to get the result you want

$(1-1) + (2-1) + (3-1) + \ldots \to \infty$

or

$(1+2+3+\ldots) - (1 + 1 + 1 + \ldots) \to 0$

Comment: Partial sums are $s_n = n(n+1)/2 - n = n(n-1)/2$ which diverges to $+\infty$. So the series does not converge.

Comment: $(1+2+3+\ldots) - (1 + 1 + 1 + \ldots) \to 0$ is not true; you *can't* compare the infinities.

Comment: In general you can only rearrange terms in specific conditions. Look up absolute convergence and conditional convergence. And also $\infty-\infty\ne 0$ (in general), as macton said. Note also that we don’t say it converges if it goes to $\infty$, but rather it diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: In words, you are asking whether the sum of all nonnegative integers is finite.  Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you taking the symbol $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(i-1)$$ to be defined as? The answer to your question is very much dependent on this. If you are taking $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(i-1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n(i-1)$$ as the definition, then the correct conclusion would be that $i-1$ is not summable, since the above limit does not exist. Just to prove that it does not exist, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n(i-1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\sum_{i=1}^ni-\sum_{i=1}^n1\right]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{n(n+1)}2-n\right]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n(n-1)}2=\infty.$$ On the other hand, if you are taking summability to defined as something else, then you need to make that definition clear with your question. It is unclear what your definitions are.